# How to set x-axis in JpGraph?

Tags: jpgraph

I have problem to set the x-axis. I want to create a monthly graph that need 1-31 days in a month on x-axis. How to set it? Tq

Answer (score 0):

create an array

```
xdata=[1,2,..,31];
```

then use this code

```
  $graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($xdata);
```